# Can I use realex payment functionality without server-side code?

Tags: realex-payments-api

I have a .NET project and wanna use "Realex Payments". It's not clear how to use it. So could somebody help me to understand?

1. Can I use just javascript API to initialize payment iframe or just
   put iframe on my page without any server-side code?
2. Should I use just javascript to initialize an payment iframe as described here? [this](https://developer.realexpayments.com/#!/hpp/customisation)
3. What javascript library should I use to initialize a payment iframe? rxp-hpp.js or rxp-js.js?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your questions.

1. You will need to use server-side code. The server-side SDK creates the request POST for the HPP which uses the Shared Secret, this must be kept securely on the server-side.
2. I can't think of a reason why you wouldn't do this. This is how [our JS Library](https://github.com/realexpayments/rxp-js) works.
3. If you are exclusively using our HPP then rxp-hpp.js will suffice. The only difference with rxp-js.js is that it contains a validation library, but that's useful only if you are collecting card data yourself in your application.

Hope that's helpful.

Best,

Seán

**Realex Payments**